# Why does R convert numbers and characters to factors when coercing to data frame?

Tags: r

Recently I have come across a problem where my data has been converted to factors.
This is a large nuisance, as it's not (always) easily picked up on.

I am aware that I can convert them back with solutions such as `as.character(paste(x))` or `as.character(paste(x))`, but that seems really unnecessary.

Example code:

```
nums <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
chars <- c("A","B","C,","D","E")
str(nums)
#>  num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
str(chars)
#>  chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C," "D" "E"
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a = nums, b = chars))
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ a: Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#>  $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C,","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: [Hence, in the R Core meetings in Toulouse in 2019, it was decided to move towards using stringsAsFactors = FALSE by default, ideally starting with the 4.0.0 release.](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't `cbind` as it converts data to matrix and matrix can hold data of only one type, so it converts numbers to characters.
2. Use `data.frame` because `as.data.frame(a = nums, b = chars)` returns an error.
3. Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` because in `data.frame` default value of
   `stringsAsFactors` is `TRUE` which converts characters to factors. The numbers also change to factors because in 1) they have been changed to characters.

   ```
   df <- data.frame(a = nums, b = chars, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    str(df)
    #'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
    # $ a: num  1 2 3 4 5
    # $ b: chr  "A" "B" "C," "D" ...
   ```

EDIT: As of the newest version of R, the default value of `stringAsFactors` has changed to `FALSE`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reasons behind it?

Comment: @mhh Updated the answer with some explanation.

Comment: thank you for the added explanation. I'm baffled over the fact that `stringsAsFactiors` is `TRUE` by default.

Comment: @mnh it is a legacy problem. luckily, everyone else is also baffled, and it will go away soon: https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html

Comment: just a minor correction, the value is not set to `TRUE`, but to `default.stringsAsFactors()` which happens to be `TRUE` by default. You can change that global value with `options()`. Even though they are not popular, a lot of functions depends on factors, so it makes sense that the default is set to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

This should no longer happen if you have updated R: data frames don't automatically turn `chr` to `fct`. In a way, data frames are now more similar to tibbles.